# JS: Increasing a selection with sibling nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a bit stuck with this...

Let's say I've got the next HTML structure:

```
<div id="sourceText" class="cSourceText" contenteditable="true">
     some text here
     <br>
     some more text here
     <br>
</div>
```

Now, let's say that I have used the js `splitText` method to store a part of the first text node in a var(i.e. `<TextNode textContent="text here">` is stored in `var newNode;`).

I want to make `newNode` var to increase with the next sibling nodes until it gets a specified point of a specified text node (wich varies depending on a user selection). Let's say, for our example, I want `newNode=>text here <br> some more`  at the end so that I can use the jQuery wrapp function to wrap that node with a div.

Is that posible? Or am I going in the wrong direction?

Comment: Given the input (your *current* HTML structure) can you show what you want the output to be? I'm afraid I didn't understand your description of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry David. Sometimes expressing complex stuffs in English it's hard for me. It's something like this:

    `<div id="sourceText" class="cSourceText" contenteditable="true">
         some <div style="background-color:red;display:inline-block">text here
         <br>
         some more</div> text here
         <br>
    </div>`

Hope it helps. Thanks for your prompt reply.

Comment: How is '_a specified point of a specified text node_' specified exactly?

Comment: I get the specified point as an offset value from the ['anchorNode'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Selection) wich is a TextNode.